# How to edit /etc/pam.d/sytem-auth-ac file in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, passwords, group-policy

I tried several times to edit this file but after several items it always show up the old default files script.
I need to replace lines or edit this file for making a User management Policy.

Commands I used in my script:

```
# sed '14 i \password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=8 lcredit=-1 dcredit=1 difok=4 maxrepeat=2 ocredit=1 ucredit=1 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac

#sed '15 i \password    sufficient    pam_unix.so shadow  try_first_pass use_authtok remember=6 /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac


#sed '4 i \auth        required      pam_tally2.so onerr=fail file=/var/log/faillog deny=6 unlock_time=3600'  /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac

#sed '10 i \account     required      pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/faillog' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac

#sed '13 i \account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so' /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac
```

Above are the commands which i write to add this in my script if anyone has some good suggestion plz put in comments. 
Help will really be appreciated.

Comment: None of your commands edit the file in place. They all just output the new contents to standard output. You need to tell sed to actually edit the file or redirect to a new file and then replace the original.

Comment: any suggestion. Etan

Comment: Yes, look into the documentation for `sed` to have it operate **i**n-place or for how to redirect to another file and then mv the new file over the old file.

Comment: thanks Etan. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

the right command for this issue is.
sed -i 's/original/modify/g' filename ( this will edit original file)
or 
sed -i 's/original/modify/g' filename > filename.bak  (this will create a new file)